# Is "Un-stick sticky search bar (like on YouTube or Facebook)" a canonical question?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, canonical-question

I have an issue with Google's recently introduced sticky search bar in its search portal. I find it annoying because it is useless to me and takes away my precious screen real estate.

I looked for various solutions and came across the question [Un-stick sticky search bar (like on Youtube or Facebook)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/58852/90094). Though none of the solutions there worked for me, I was able to create a solution on my own for  my problem.

I, now, intend to provide the solution so that others can benefit. However, I'm confused as whether I should ask a new question (which I risk being closed as a duplicate of the linked one) or I should just post my solution to the linked question?

What should I do now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you should post a new question instead of adding a response to the referred one as it's too broad, IMHO, because it's not about a specific web app while yours is.

On the other hand, the referred question should be closed for the reason mentioned above; it's not about a specific web app.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense.  I have taken the liberty to add a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123374/90094) and self-answer it.